# Passing date/time to cron job command

Tags: cron

Is there any possibility to pass current date/time to command in my cron job?
E.g. I want to make sql dump every night and name the dump file like 'dump-yyyy-mm-dd.sql'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be something along the lines of:

```
mysqldump database > database-$(date +%F).sql
```

The `$()` will embed the output of `date +%F`, which is `YYYY-MM-DD` into the command line.

Comment: You should be careful to escape %s with backslashes in your format string if you're using a POSIX compliant cron, otherwise everything after the first % will be treated as standard input for the command.  Check `man 5 crontab` for details on this surprising yet fun feature.

Answer (score 6):

Sgaduuw's answer does work (and I've upvoted it), but I usually encourage people to write scripts and call those from cron, rather than try and do too much in the cron command directly.  Firstly, it allows you to easily test / enhance your script without having to mess with cron configuration, and secondly it allows you to be in better control of the environment in which your commands execute.